# Find the number of intersecting circles

Tags: algorithm

I came upon an interview question, that I couldn't solve:

Given an array A of N integers, we draw N discs in a 2D plane such that the I<sup>th</sup> disc is centered on (0,I) and has a radius of A[I]. We say that the J<sup>th</sup> disc and K<sup>th</sup> disc intersect if J ≠ K and J<sup>th</sup> and K<sup>th</sup> discs have at least one common point.
Write a function:
int solution(const vector &A);
that, given an array A describing N discs as explained above, returns the number of pairs of intersecting discs. For example, given N=6 and:

```
A[0] = 1  A[1] = 5  A[2] = 2 
A[3] = 1  A[4] = 4  A[5] = 0
```

intersecting discs appear in eleven pairs of elements:

```
0 and 1,
0 and 2,
0 and 4,
1 and 2,
1 and 3,
1 and 4,
1 and 5,
2 and 3,
2 and 4,
3 and 4,
4 and 5.
```

so the function should return 11.

So far it is not difficult, you can find the intersection between each two circles, either by calculating the intersection using the circle equation or even simpler, they intersect if  the distance between the two centers is larger than the sum of the two radii. This solution requires O(N<sup>2</sup>).

Well the constraint is that the interviewee should present a solution with worst time complexity O(N.logN) and requires space O(N). As a hint give: the elements of the array can be edited.

Whenevr logN said, it pops to my head a tree or a recursion, but then again I can't create new data structure as space required is O(N). So I can only imagine that there's only one for loop done on the array and on each step a recursion of some kind is done and altering the array value as needed. But this is as far I've come. Any ideas are appreciated

Comment: Test whether each pair intersect. That takes O(N**2) time.

Comment: @ColonelPanic so that means it's not the answer..

Comment: @ColonelPanic I implicitly wrote that we can compare each two circles whoch yields O(N^2). I edited the question to make it clearer

Comment: O(N) space is enough to build a tree.

Comment: @JurajBlaho yah but I thought because the input size is O(N) you are not allowed to create anymore data structures and just use what's available

Comment: I think that you can create another data structere of size say N or 2*N etc. it's still O(N). This exercise seems like good fit for Dynamic Programming.